# Using recursion to generate the correct output for a sequence

Tags: c++, recursion, integer

I'm trying to use recursion to solve a function that returns the nth number of a sequence. It goes as follows:

The sequence begins with the number 4. Every following number is three times the previous number, then added by 1. For instance, these are the first several numbers of the sequence: 1, 4, 13, 40, 121, 364, etc.

```
int recursive_sequence(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return 1; // This is base case
    }
    else
    {
        return 4 + (3 * (n-1) + 1) + recursive_sequence(n-1); // This is recursive case
    }
}
```

I attempted this by starting with the number 4, then "3 times the previous number, add 1", then calling the recursion function to go down to the next number. If "n" is inputted as "4", for example, then the correct output would be 40 since 3 * (13) + 1 = 40. However, as an example, with my code, I got 34. What am I doing wrong? If you can, please include an example in your answer (it would be greatly appreciated!).

Comment: Your posted code won't compile due to lack of semicolon in the 2nd `return` line. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why do you start from 4 while the first number is 1? Why don't you use simple straight-forward formula for "3 times the number before it, add 1": `3 * recursive_sequence(n-1) + 1`?

Comment: I think I got confused about the wording of the question (with the "first number starts with 4"). I overlooked it and continued on which does not seem like the best idea.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice "The first number starts with 4.", but "the first several numbers" starts from 1...?

Comment: Yes, I realize my mistake - I focused on the wording explanation rather than the sample example. Many apologies.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: I apologize, I only found out that notion just now. Will remember this going forward.

Comment: Are you required to use recursion? There is a closed-form solution (3^n-1)/2 (which, incidentally, is going to overflow quite quickly).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I have to use recursion

Answer (score 2):

The first number is 1, not 4. Therefore, you should start from 1.

Then, you should simply write "3 times the number before it, add 1" as a formula.

```cpp
int recursive_sequence(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return 1; // start from 1
    }
    else
    {
        return 3 * recursive_sequence(n-1) + 1; // 3 times the number before it, add 1
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I have been putting everything in front of my recursion, thinking I had to do the recursion last.